# What does "projecting" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I meet this word in a article. After look up dictionary, I am not sure what it means in this context

> “Pfft,” she says, waving a hand. “He’s nervous. Everything he says,
>   he’s always **projecting**. He knows the case that can be made against
>   him. That’s why he’s falling apart.”
>
> But you’re not, I ask?
>
> “No,” she says, her voice steady. “I’m emboldened.”

Source : https://time.com/5762021/nancy-pelosi-trump-impeachment-gamble/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is from psychology.

> Projection is the process of displacing one’s feelings onto a
>   different person, animal, or object. The term is most commonly used to
>   describe defensive projection—attributing one’s own unacceptable urges
>   to another. The concept emerged from Sigmund Freud’s work in the
>   1890s.

[Projection (Psychology Today)](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/basics/projection)